# Keep column creation to a limit in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code I compiled based on some stuff I found online.
It works (mostly) as I intend it to, as on change in column H it creates a new column to the right of the last column, in the active row, with the latest value.

However, I'd like, if possible, the following:

- to keep only the latest 5 changes;
- currently, it somehow always ignores the fact that the last column of the active row is empty and just creates a new column after so my updates always [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkXJ.png), even if each of them is the first update for each row (I can expand if this wasn't clear enough).

Here's the VBA code I have now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
a = Sheets("SORTIES").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Column = Split(Cells(1, a).Address, "$")(1)
    
Sheets("SORTIES").Range(Column & ActiveCell.Row).Value = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *currently, it somehow always ignores the fact that the last column of the active row is empty and just creates a new column after* - that's because your data is a table. Work with the `ListObject` in vba to enter your data into the last column in the listobject.

Comment: Not so clear what you want accomplishing. Talking about "5 changes" do you mean the late 5 changes on each row, or totally? Then, as the above comment states, the last column is calculated outside the existing table. What do you need from this point of view? To be inside of the table and insert a new column only if there will not be place on the specific row?

Comment: @FaneDuru I meant the last 5 changes per row. As for the second question, I believe it would make life easier if the 'updates' would be in the same table as well, yes, a new column would need to be inserted only if there is no available space in the row.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. I suppose that `Sheets("SORTIES")` is the active sheet. Is that assumption true?

Comment: Oh, that's great! That's true, it is the active sheet. Multumesc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It determines the last empty column inside the table and uses a `Static` dictionary variable, to keep records for all the cells in the table, for H:H column. It needs a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". To add this reference you need to be in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor) and go `Tools` (menu) -> `References...`, scroll down until find "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library, check it and press `OK`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static dictSt As New Dictionary 'it needs a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$E$1" And Target.Value = "x" Then dictSt.RemoveAll: Target.Value = "": Exit Sub 'clear the dictionary
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lstO As ListObject: Set lstO = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1) 'use your table namem if there is not only one
        If dictSt.count = 0 Then 'load the dictionary for first time
            'load the dictionary referenced cells
            Dim arrRng As Range, i As Long, cel As Range
            Set arrRng = Intersect(lstO.DataBodyRange, Range("H:H"))
            For Each cel In arrRng.cells
                dictSt(cel.Address) = 0
            Next
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, lstO.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            Dim lastEmptRng As Range
             Set lastEmptRng = cells(lastListCol(Target, lstO)(0), lastListCol(Target, lstO)(1))
             
             'operate the change in the dictionary and use the last history value after 5 records
             If dictSt(Target.Address) >= 5 Then
                Dim arrVal As Variant, arrUpdate As Variant, El
                arrVal = Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), cells(Target.row, lastEmptRng.Column - 1)).Value
                ReDim arrUpdate(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrVal, 2))
                For i = 1 To UBound(arrVal, 2) - 1
                   arrUpdate(1, i) = arrVal(1, i + 1)
                Next
                arrUpdate(1, 5) = Target.Value
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                    Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), cells(Target.row, lastEmptRng.Column - 1)).Value = arrUpdate
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With
             Else
                lastEmptRng.Value = Target.Value
                dictSt(Target.Address) = dictSt(Target.Address) + 1
             End If
            Target.Select
        End If
   End If
End Sub

Private Function lastListCol(tg As Range, lstO As ListObject) As Variant
  'this piece of code search the last empty column (of the Target row) inside the table!
  Dim listRow As Long, fRng As Range
  
   listRow = tg.row - lstO.DataBodyRange.row + 1
   Set fRng = lstO.DataBodyRange.rows(listRow).Find(What:="*", _
           After:=lstO.DataBodyRange.cells(listRow, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
            lastListCol = Array(tg.row, fRng.Column + 1) ' Stop
        Else
            lastListCol = Array(tg.row, lstO.DataBodyRange.cells(listRow, 1).Column)
        End If
End Function
```

The dictionary can be reset by typing "x" in cell "E1"!

Edited:

Now, it keeps the last records for all recording history.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223159/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-keep-column-creation-to-a-limit-in-vba).